# Why am I getting this Authenticate message all of a sudden when I try to shut down my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop?

Tags: shutdown, authentication

It asks for my password to authenticate a shutdown. This never happened to me before, am I hacked?

This is the message,
"Authentication is required for powering off the system while an application asked to inhibit it.

An application is attempting to perform an action that requires privleges. Authentication is required to perform this acton."

When I clicked details this information is shown.

"Action: org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-ignore-inhibit

Vendor: The systemd Project"

UPDATE: I closed a system software update without finishing it because it took too long.

Comment: Closing a system software update would indeed prompt for a password, so this seems like expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you user535733!